# Values returned from image.onload(function() are 0 or undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get height/width from some background images, but how to get these values into some variables?

```
var bgobj = jQuery(this);  // assigning the object          
    var url = bgobj.css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$|"/ig, '');

    var img = new Image();

    img.src = url;
```

Option 1:

```
    alert('img.width: ' + img.width); // alert: " img.width: 0 "
```

Probably, the image hasn't loaded. So I try onload: 
Option 2:

```
   jQuery(bgimg).on('load', function() {
            height = jQuery(bgimg).height();  
            //alert('height ' + height); //'480px' which is correct!
    });
```

No way to get the value out for further use!? So I try callback:
Option 3:

```
        var imageSize = function(url, callback) {

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){

                var response = {};
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    var x = img.width;
                    var y = img.height;
                    var z = y/x;
                    response = {width:x,height:y};
                    if(callback) callback(response);
                }
                img.src = url;
            }               
            img.onload();               

    }
    var getSize = function(url, callback) {
        imageSize(url, function(response)   {
            var dim = response;
        })
        callback(dim);
    }
    var h;
    imageSize(img.src, function(response) {
            h=response.height;
            //alert(h); // 800px (OK))
    })
    //alert(h);  //undefined    
    //alert(imageSize.height); //undefined
    //alert(imageSize.h); //undefined
    //alert(imageSize.response.h); //undefined
```

Still no way to get the value into an ordinary variable.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your only problem is the inherent async nature of this problem. The browser has to load the image, before you can access any of its properties. So you wont be able to get the dimensions of that image in a strictly sync workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've overcomplicated it, but option 3 is *one* way to do it.

```js
var imageSize = function(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){        
      if(callback) callback(img.width,img.height);    
    }   
    img.src = url;    
}

$(function(){
    var url = $('#foo').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$|"/ig, '');
    imageSize(url,function(w,h){
      alert("width=" + w + ", height=" + h);  
    })
});
```

```css
#foo{
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

The thing to remember is that the method `imageSize` is asynchronous, so you must pass it a callback which will be called when the image has loaded. You cant have another method where you treat it as a synchronous call, that just wont work.

Comment: Great! Only thing I miss now, is how to pass the values w and h to (global) variables outside this function? Somehow I cant find any understandable explanation.

Comment: @knottulf - The same way as you do in your example, but it makes no sense to do so. That variable will only be set once the callback has been called, so trying to read them directly afterwards wont work. Whatever work you need to do with `w` and `h` must be triggered by the callback.

Comment: What I really need here, is the proportions width/height, which I need to re-use. For instance to solve repositioning in parallax scrolling, orientation change and more. So somehow I'll have to pass the values to some other functions?

Comment: so call another function in the callback (or better yet pass the function in): `imageSize(url, setupParallax)`